# Codeigniter extend helper but want to call old helper

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing an Application in Bonfire.

They have extended the form helper.

Is there a way to call the original form helper from Codigniter  without removing the extended one from Bonfire?

Answer (score 1):

"Helpers" are just files with PHP functions in them. They aren't actually "extended", Codeigniter loads it's default helpers *after* loading yours, and checks if you "overwrote" a function like so:

```
if ( ! function_exists('form_open'))
{
    function form_open() {/* default code */}
}
```

So unfortunately, no - there's no way to call the original function if you already declared your own.

**HOWEVER**: It appears that Bonfire does the exact same thing, checking with `function_exists`, so if you want to - you should be able to load your own form helper before it, but you still cannot simply load the original one without hacking Bonfire and removing the functions (which could have terrible side effects).

Comment: you're right, they're not actually being extended. Thanks
I find it strange why they even customised the form_helper. Their version wraps everything in a div.

Comment: If it were a class instead of a bunch of global functions, it would be easier. What was the specific thing you had an issue with? Maybe you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: The Bonfire version of form_dropdown is wrapped in divs. I just want to use the CI form_dropdown where I can use my own layout
 
`<div class="control-group {$error}">
 <label class="control-label" for="{$defaults['name']}">{$label}</label>
 <div class="controls">
   <select {$output} {$extra}>
   {$options_vals}
  </select>
  {$tooltip}
 </div>
</div>`

Comment: I;m just going to do a find and replace and rename Bonfire form_dropdown to form_bi_dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same prob, user742736's comment is the only answer that solved the prob.
Explained in detail, may be this can help some one

You can create your own helper function with out the divs surrounding the drop down here
bonfire/application/helpers/MY_form_helper.php
make a copy of the function form_dropdown, name it like form_dropdown_plain

modify the last few lines of the function to output with out divs

call  form_dropdown_plain instead of form_dropdown

Comment: Consider using code blocks; either indent code four spaces or surround it with the ` character